# How do i convert from a set to a list within a method call?

Tags: java, list, methods, set

I would like to convert from a set to a List within a method call. Right now this is what i do :

```
List<Integer> lrsIdList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
lrsIdList.addAll(repaymentMap.keySet());
getObjects(lrsIdList)
```

How do i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `repaymentMap.keySet()` returns the `Set<Integer>`

```
getObjects(new ArrayList<Integer>(repaymentMap.keySet()));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the Set to a List by passing the Set instance into the constructor of a List implementation class such as ArrayList.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(hashset);
```